# How do I index or choose a database if the query pattern is very broad

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, indexing, data-modeling

I am strugling to figure how do I choose or even index my database if the requirements are very broad

Lets say my table will have 10 fields. And the requirement is queries can generally be on 1 or 2 fields but in potentially most permutations of fields

How do I approach this problem? I definately dont think indexing all fields is a good idea but I struggle to figure how best to approach this issue

I currently use Mongo for this, however a few challenges faced so far:

- Number of records now: 110m+
- Index size is already a whopping 0.15TB
- Paginating thru to a high page number is slow on mongo
- In many cases I need to join/lookup (coupled with pagination is very very slow)

I am considering Postgres. Mainly cos I can use RDS and if need migrate to Aurora. Currently, I needed to self manage Mongo which is also challenging to scale. But even Postgres may not be ideal for this? I guess the indexing part will be a similar challenge? Tho maybe the joins / pagination part will do better?